# Alarms before alarm time

Tags: android, time, notifications

Please help me guys Im creating an alarm clock project and i have a problem.

This is the problem i need to set an alarm before the current time like if the time now is 1:00pm ill set 10:00am so basically it has 18 hours remaining and 59 minutes before alarm time, the problem is once you set an alarm like 10:00am on 1:00pm time it will alarm just after you click ok

```
                    if (setHour < c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                            || setHour == c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                            && setMinute < c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {

                        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, setHour);
                        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, setMinute);
                        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        client.setAlarmNotification(c, requestCode);

                    }
```

setHour is from timepicker as well as setMinute. Requestcode is unique as it comes from id from database (PrimaryKey) so no problem with that, it all works when you alarm after the current time but NOT before the current time . Guys please help me im dealing with this for couple of days now. thank you in  advance

-raphaelle

Comment: Hi @raphaelle I am not sure but may be because you are setting `HOUR_OF_DAY`. It is use for the 24-hour clock. So may be it consider that your hour may be passed. Coz it is not considering next 24 hours. You can just try with `DAY_OF_*` params and let me know what is exact problem.. See this doc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you just need to set alarm for next day.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (setHour < c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
|| setHour == c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
&& setMinute < c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) 
{
     c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, setHour);
     c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, setMinute);
     c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
     time = time + 1000*60*60*24; // Add 24h to the date
     c.setTimeInMillis(time);
     client.setAlarmNotification(c, requestCode);
}
```

Comment: @nilkash idk if 12 hour will do but ill also try that thanks :D

Comment: its not working @goodm like i thought it will register for the next day (tomorrow ). but when you change your time on ur phone it should alarm but in this case no because it is set for the next day. any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the calendar to the time AND date you wish to use instead of only setting the time.

```
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year,month,day,hour,minute);
    client.setAlarmNotification(c, requestCode);
```

Note: Months are 0 to 11 NOT 1 to 12

If you just want to fire the alarm tomorrow, then add a day to the calender like this:

```
  c.add(Calendar.DATE,1); // Add one day to the calendar
```

Then you need only set the time.

Comment: yes thats a great idea but the problem is when you change the time on your phone it wont alarm cuz you set the alarm for the next day.

Comment: The alarm will fire at the time you set it to. 'Calendar.getInstance' returns a calendar that *is set to the CURRENT date and time* so by setting only the time, this is what you are doing anyway but you are setting your alarm in the past.

Comment: like I said when i put day on calendar, it will register only for that day but not today, imagine when you set an alarm 10:00am when it is already 1:00pm so basically it should be tomorrow but when you change ur time on ur phone it wont trigger the alarm cuz it is set for the next day.

Comment: You are missing the point. Set the DATE as well then it will fire the next day. If you do not set the date then you are essentially giving it the CURRENT date i.e TODAY. I give up.

Comment: alright wait, so ill set the day, month and year? these 3 are current right?

Comment: 'Calendar.getInstance' returns the current date and time. Therefore if it is now 1PM and you set the time of the calendar to 10AM then you are setting it to 3 hours ago and so the alarm will fire right away. If instead you set the you set the date to be the next day and also set the time to be 10AM, you are setting the alarm to fire at 10AM tomorrow.

Comment: If you are finding that your timers are not firing if you manipulate the date and time on the device then you should ask a new question giving the relevant information as the question you asked here (*why does alarm fire right away*) has now been answered.

Comment: but it is not intentionally set for tomorrow but it should waiit for another 24 hours not specifically "tomorrow".

Comment: if you don't want it set for tomorrow then set it to whatever date you actually do want.  If you always want to fire the next day then see the second part of my answer. The alarm will fire at the Time and Date that YOU SET. I do not understand what you are finding difficult about this simple fact.

Comment: is it ok if i ask for your facebook or email so i can send you my files my friend.

Comment: it shouldnt trigger alarm even if you set a time that is already pass, thats the problem and putting a day specifically is not the answer which you were suggesting.

Comment: This is the last time I am going to say it. A calendar object consists of a DATE and a TIME. If you do not specifically set a date on it then you are essentially saying "Use todays date" as that is the default date returned from 'Calendar.getInstance()'. If you set an alarm to a time in the past then it will always fire right away. If you set the calendar to a date and time in the future, then that future date is when the alarm will fire. This is a fact. This is the answer to the question you asked and nothing will change that. Read the Calendar docs.